# Cannot show view without index.php in a url except in the default controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a routing issue in CodeIgniter, i have searched and tried other links on stackoverflow including [Removing index.php in CodeIgniter just works for the default controller URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235941/removing-index-php-in-codeigniter-just-works-for-the-default-controller-url) but my problem did'nt solved. When i run from this url http://localhost/MyProject/ it successfully gives output the view page of test.php page, but the problem is suppose there is test2 view and controller also, so i can't load it directly by this url http://localhost/MyProject/test2 , but i can load it through http://localhost/MyProject/index.php/test2. I want that i can run my code without index.php in between url i.e. by http://localhost/MyProject/test2.

```
View
```

> test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<head>  
    <title>Welcome Test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`Controller`

> test.php

```
<?php
class test extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
?>
```

> ```
> routes.php
> ```

```
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
```

> .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On
 #rename "MyProject/" with your application directory 
 #For example you rename the entire CodeIgniter application as "mysite" 
 #then, the "RewriteBase /" will be like this "RewriteBase /mysite" 
 #same as at line number 10, "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MyProject//index.php #/$1 [L]" will be like this "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]"
 RewriteBase /MyProject/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MyProject/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove index.php from your url.Create .htacces file and place in your root.Copy this code and run

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

for more how to remove index.php form url try this http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/

Comment: i tried your code and typed the following url http://localhost/MyProject/test it is giving error 404 page not found.

Comment: but through http://localhost/MyProject/index.php/test it is working i don't want index.php in between.

Comment: Open config.php file insie the config folder and replace     $config['index_page'] = "index.php"
to
$config['index_page'] = ""

Comment: try to replcae $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"

Comment: the issue is same, is there any problem with .haccess file:             <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

***FYI***

**Recommended  `.htaccess` is**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```