# Remove index.php from url for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have done all that I know how to do and I need help.

I am working with someone to create an internal website on Windows Server 2008 using DNS and IIS. We have got it set up that when we type test.site is will access our website folder that is located in D:/intranet.

I added my site that I built using the Codeigniter framework. All is fine when I visit my site in the browser at http://fallspointe.resources. It loads and there is nothing wrong. When I access my login page at http://fallspointe.resources/index.php/admin/user/login it loads and everything works great. On my local computer I use mamp (mac computer) so I use .htaccess to rewrite the url so that I can go to http://fallspointe.resources/admin/user/login without the index.php. After searching I found out that you can't use .htaccess to rewrite the url, instead you use the web.config file.

This is where I run into problems. No matter what I put in the web.config file. Nothing changes. I keep getting the same error page. I noticed that the "Detailed Error Information" shows that the physical path I'm trying to access when I try to go to http://fallspointe.resources/admin/user/login is D:\intranet\admin\user\login which isn't really true. I have tried everything and it still doesn't seem to be either reading my web.config file or something. Below is one of the rewrite rules I tried to use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if I have it in the wrong place, or I have to use a different path for my index.php file. I must be doing something so simple wrong, because I can find nothing on the internet about this problem.

Also, below is my error page I keep getting.

[image]

PLEASE HELP! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097003/cannot-show-view-without-index-php-in-a-url-except-in-the-default-controller-in/33097137#33097137

Answer (score 0):

Your *ReWrite URL* is fine.

Check this

1. In `Config/config.php` change this

   - `$config['base_url'] = '';`
   - `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
2. In `routes.php` check

   - `default_controller` is defined.

> **Note:** When I load this [`http://fallspointe.resources/`](http://fallspointe.resources/) URL Its not load at all. So check **all the files are uploaded** as well as Be s**ure about Naming Conversations**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is actually an internal site. It's only viewable on the network. I added the 'index.php' to my config file. However, it shows in the url (fallspointe.resources/index.php/admin/user/login). It just seems like IIS isn't even reading my web.config file.